# In Scipy why does custom.rvs() having uniform probability return the values in the begining region only?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, probability

If I generate a array

```
custom=np.ones(800, dtype=np.float32)
```

Then create a Custom Probability distribution out of it using

```
custom=normalize(custom)[0]
customPDF = stats.rv_discrete(name='pdfX', values=(np.arange(800), custom))
```

Then if I use

```
customPDF.rvs()
```

I get values returned in the range 0 - 20, whereas i expect random numbers varying from 0 to 800.

The following code gives me required output,

```
random.uniform(0,800)
```

But due to the necessity of being able to manipulate the probability distribution through altering the custom array, i have to use **customPDF.rvs()**

is there a solution to this or why this is happening??

---

```
In [206]: custom=np.ones(800, dtype=np.float32)

In [207]: custom=normalize(custom)[0]
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:386: DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and willraise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
  DeprecationWarning)

In [208]: customPDF = stats.rv_discrete(name='pdfX', values=(np.arange(800), custom))

In [209]: customPDF.rvs()
Out[209]: 7

In [210]: customPDF.rvs()
Out[210]: 13

In [211]: customPDF.rvs()
Out[211]: 15

In [212]: customPDF.rvs()
Out[212]: 3

In [213]: customPDF.rvs()
Out[213]: 8

In [214]: customPDF.rvs()
Out[214]: 10

In [215]: customPDF.rvs()
Out[215]: 10

In [216]: customPDF.rvs()
Out[216]: 11

In [217]: customPDF.rvs()
Out[217]: 15

In [218]: customPDF.rvs()
Out[218]: 6

In [219]: customPDF.rvs()
Out[219]: 7

In [220]: random.uniform(0,800)
Out[220]: 707.0265562968543
```

Comment: please add your imports. You are using a couple of functions out of nowhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
custom=normalize(custom)[0]
```

Based on the warning, it looks like `normalize` refers to [`sklearn.preprocessing.normalize`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html). `normalize` expects an `[n_samples, n_features]` 2D array - since you give it a 1D vector it will insert a new dimension and treat it as a `[1, n_features]` array (hence why you are indexing the 0th element of the output).

By default it will adjust the [L2 (Euclidean) norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Euclidean_norm) of each row of features to be equal to 1. This is *not* the same as making the elements sum to 1:

```
print(normalize(np.ones(800))[0].sum())
# 28.2843
```

Since the sum of `custom` is much greater than 1, the cumulative probability of drawing a particular integer reaches 1 before you get to the end of the probability vector:

```
print(custom.cumsum().searchsorted(1))
# 28
```

The consequence is that you will never draw an integer larger than 28:

```
print(customPDF.rvs(size=100000).max())
# 28
```

What you ought to in order to normalize `custom` is divide by its sum:

```
custom /= custom.sum()

# or alternatively:
custom = np.repeat(1./800, 800)
```